# Ajaxful-rating: multiple ratings on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ajaxful-rating ([ajaxful-rating on github](http://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/tree/master)) and come across an issue.

I display a list of items and want to rate/display the rate of each item.
The problem is that the link_to_remote all point to the same item_id.
I've looked at the source, but (being new to Ruby / RoR), I find it hard to identify the source of the problem.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Is it an issue with the gem or should I rather find the solution in *my* code?

```
<% @bookmark.each do |link| %>
<li>
<%= link_to link.title, bookmark_path(link), :target => "_blank" %>              
<%if current_user.id == link.user_id%>
<%= link_to image_tag("pencil.png"), edit_pointer_path(link)%>
<%else%>
(shared by <%=link.user.login%>)
<%end%>
<br/>
(viewed <%=pluralize(link.visits,'time')%>)
<%= ratings_for link, :small_stars => true%>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yep, tell me if you need more